# Java With mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a mysql table and records as follows.

```
create table  if not exists price (
    price_id varchar(30) not null,
    econ_price float(10,3),
    business_price float(10,3),
    platinum_price float(10,3),
    primary key(price_id)
);

insert into price values('1',334,556,788);
insert into price values('2',3500,5500,7000);
insert into price values('3',1000,5500,7400);
insert into price values('4',1000,5500,7400);
```

If I know the price type (econ or business or platinum) and price_id, how can I want to get the price? These are my java codes.

```
public int setPrice(String price_id, String type){
     .........................
     return price;
}

int price1 = setPrice(3,'econ');
int price2 = setPrice(4,'platinum');
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you asking how to code a dao method to retrieve the price from the database?

Comment: It's make me confuse , what actually you want to say? .

Comment: I cannot understand how to write that mysql query. But I can find the price if my table is like follows...............................       create table  if not exists price (
    price_id varchar(30) not null,
    type varchar(30),price float(10,3)     ,                                                                                                                                 
    primary key(price_id,type)
);

Comment: Then I can use ,,,,,,,, SELECT price FROM price WHERE price_id=? AND type =?;

Comment: But in this type of table, it is difficult to write the query.

Answer (score 0):

Per the post, you already know the type. So, a very blunt approach would be to have a switch/conditional select statements based on the known types.

```
...
if ("econ".equals(type)) {
    sql = "select econ_price from price where price_id = ?";
} else if ("platinum".equals(type) {
    sql = "select platinum_price from price where price_id = ?";
} else {
...
}
```

Note, this is a very blunt approach and there may be other ways to solve the problem. However, this does answer the question asked.

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22745755)

Comment: It would be great if you can add more details